# Open Source optical touchscreen software for Windows

Tags: windows, kinect, multi-touch, kinect-sdk

For quite some time I've been looking into using a camera pointed at a screen to make a touchscreen. I always liked the idea of using a Kinect or some other IR/3D camera to do so. Unfortunately it seems as though development of any "touchscreen for Kinect" projects has all but stopped since 2013.

All I want to do is point a camera at a TV, run Windows (Windows 10 preferably) on the TV, and touch the TV like a giant iPad. No crazy 3D gesture nonsense, just the exact same functionality you'd get from a normal capacitive mult-touch capable touchscreen.

I've looked into just about every touchscreen project I could find online, the popular ones being:

- [touchlesstouch](http://www.touchlesstouch.com/)
- Ludique's Kinect Bundle
- Ubi-Interactive, but I don't want to pay that much to use more than one finger at a time
- [openni](http://openni.ru/) Looked promising until it didn't let me download anything. Plus anything related to Primesense is automatically out since Apple bought them 2 years ago.
- Plus lots of random projects from MSDN or kinecthacks.com

Basically anything that's still available to download doesn't compile or crashes the second it runs because who knows why.

There's also annoyingly unhelpful things like [this](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/137630-using-kinect-to-turn-any-surface-into-a-multi-user-multi-finger-touchscreen), or [this](http://www.covii.pt/guineapig/viihaptic-software/) that shows it can work, but is unavailable to the public.

I've tried several hand-tracking solutions as well, nothing compiled or ran. If I could just get some hand tracking software working I'm sure I could figure out how to add touchscreen functionality to it.

I'm pretty well versed in C++, and have used Python before, but never anything with object detection. I have no idea where I'd even start with something like hand detection.  I've made another question asking how I'd get started building the software from the ground up myself.

So is my only option to either pay Ubi-Interactive, or to write my own software? Are there still middleware libraries that would make that a little less daunting a task to undertake?